# When is disk space made available again after dropping a mySQL table?

Tags: mysql, storage

If I drop an innodb table when will the disk space be reclaimed? 
Does it happen immediately?

How about with records instead of the entire table?

Comment: @Eugen Rieck: even when table is dropped?  why??

Comment: INNODB has tablespaces - (big) files that are used to store the database. You define them (including a possible definition to grow if necessary), but they will never schrink. Any free space is reserved for future use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on whether you enabled the `innodb_file_per_table` server setting or not.

If `innodb_file_per_table` is enabled, then each table stores its data in a separate .ibd file. Otherwise the data for all tables is stored in a shared .ibd file.

With `innodb_file_per_table`:

- When you drop a table the .ibd file is deleted and the disk space is immediately freed.
- When you delete records it frees up space inside the .ibd file, but does not shrink it. Rebuilding the table (such as by running `OPTIMIZE TABLE`) will free up the disk space.

Without `innodb_file_per_table`:

- Dropping a table or deleting rows from a table frees up space in the shared .ibd file to be used to store future data, but the shared .ibd file will never shrink